# Get RegionPass analysis information from a FunctionPass

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a RegionPass whose analysis results I want to use in a FunctionPass.

```
class RPass : public RegionPass{
    bool runOnRegion(...) { ... };
}

class FPass : public FunctionPass {
    bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
        // Get a list of regions in the function
        auto RI = &getAnalysis<RegionInfoPass>().getRegionInfo();
        std::deque<Region *> RQ = getRegionList(RI->getTopLevelRegion());

        for(Region *R : RQ){
            /* In this step, I want to get the analysis results 
             * for the Region from the RPass */
            RPass *RPI = &getAnalysis<RPass>(R);
            ...
        }
    }
    void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU){
        AU.addRequired<RPass>();
        ...
        AU.setPreservesAll();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the only functions available are *getAnalysis()* and *getAnalysis(Function &F)*.

*RPass *RPI = &getAnalysis();* causes the runtime error:

```
Assertion 'ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that wa not " "'required' by pass!"' failed
```

and *RPass *RPI = &getAnalysis(R);* causes the compile error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'FPass::getAnalysis(llvm::Region*&)
```

Any ideas on how to get the required information? The documentation on writing LLVM passes leads to a dead end.

Comment: where is `getRegionList`function defined? Is it some internal LLVM function?

Comment: `getRegionList` is a function I wrote that gets a list of all sub-regions within a region. It is basically the same as `addRegionIntoQueue()` as defined in `RegionPass.cpp:40`